# Is there a way to run the new Paint Tool SAI version (1.2.0) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I am a digital artist, and I found out that Paint Tool SAI would be the best program available for my art. I have found a few tutorials on how to run PTS on Ubuntu, however there are a few issues. One of them being that on the tutorials the version of Ubuntu is 12.04, a no longer supported version. I use Ubuntu 14.04. And, the other issue is that Paint Tool SAI has updated, the tutorials used the 1.1.0 version of PTS, now the newest version is 1.2.0. And the 1.1.0 is nowhere to be found in the original systemax website.
So, can anyone help me out? Is there any way for me to run the new Paint Tool SAI (1.2.0) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is still supported. It's an LTS (Long Term support) version supported till 2017.